# Material UI: Element to occupy whole remaining width of the Grid?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, grid

How do I force child element to occupy remaining width of the grid (Material UI)?.

I want "User Name" text field to occupy the remaining space of the grid cell. Unfortunately I am not able to do it.

I tried nested containers also but not success.

[image]

```
import {
  Grid,
  IconButton,
  InputAdornment,
  Link,
  Paper,
  TextField,
} from "@mui/material";
import Visibility from "@mui/icons-material/Visibility";
import React from "react";
import LoginIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Login";

function Login(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Paper
        elevation={24}
        sx={{
          width: 300,
          p: 2,
          borderRadius: 1,
          border: 0,
          backgroundColor: "white",
        }}
      >
        <Grid
          container
          justifyContent={"center"}
          direction={"column"}
          rowGap={2}
        >
          <Grid container direction={"column"}>
            <Grid container direction={"row"} alignItems={"flex-end"}>
              <Grid sx={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
                <LoginIcon
                  fontSize="medium"
                  sx={{ color: "green" }}
                ></LoginIcon>
              </Grid>
              <Grid sx={{ backgroundColor: "pink" }} xs={"auto"}>
                <TextField
                  fullWidth
                  inputProps={{ style: { fontSize: ".9em" } }}
                  InputLabelProps={{ style: { fontSize: ".9em" } }}
                  id="standard-basic"
                  label="User Name"
                  variant="standard"
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>           
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Login;
```

Please be informed, for brevity, I have copied only the relevant code working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by giving auto value to 1st cell and xs to 2nd cell (grid)

```
  <Grid item sx={{ backgroundColor: "red" }} xs={"auto"}> // <------- xs={"auto"}
                <LoginIcon
                  fontSize="medium"
                  sx={{ color: "green" }}
                ></LoginIcon>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item sx={{ backgroundColor: "pink" }} xs> // <------- xs
                <TextField
                  fullWidth
                  inputProps={{ style: { fontSize: ".9em" } }}
                  InputLabelProps={{
                    style: { fontSize: ".9em", color: "lightgray" },
                  }}
                  id="standard-basic"
                  label="User Name"
                  variant="standard"
                />
              </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

flexGrow is a way to go:

```
<Grid item xs={true} sx={{ backgroundColor: "pink", flexGrow: 1 }}>
              <TextField
                fullWidth
                inputProps={{ style: { fontSize: ".9em" } }}
                InputLabelProps={{ style: { fontSize: ".9em" } }}
                id="standard-basic"
                label="User Name"
                variant="standard"
              />
            </Grid>
```

Reference: https://mui.com/system/flexbox/#flex-grow